# function(a){ var a='test'; } : Is "var" required? What if a is undefined?

Tags: javascript, variables

Quite a javascript 101 question, but, here goes:

```
function test(a){
    var a='test';
}
```

Is the "var" required to keep the variable from going global?

```
function test(a){
    a='test';
}
```

Would this suffice?

How about if the function is called with a undefined?

```
function test(a){
    a='test';
}
test();
```

In the above snippet, would a become global?

Comment: From [Javascript Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp): A variable declared (using var) within a JavaScript function becomes local to the function. The variable gets a local scope: It can only be accessed from within that function. Local variables can have the same name in different functions, because they are only recognized by the function in which they are declared.

Parameter arguments work as local variables inside functions.

Local variables are create when the function starts, and deleted when the function is completed.

Comment: Arguments are local variables, so as long as you have an argument named a, you shouldn't use var, as you're just assigning a value to an already existing variable, regardless of how the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every parameter is implicitly a `var`.

(The argument value supplied doesn't matter.)

Comment: while all the other answers are detailed, and appreciated... i chose to go with this one as its the most clear and to the point. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `"use strict"` then if you don't use `var`, `a` will be attached to the global namespace implicitly, which in a browser is equivalent to `window.a`. This is known as "polluting the global namespace" and is generally considered bad practice.

This is not the same as a formal argument bound to a name, as is in your examples. This lives in the function scope as 'a'

However, if you use `"use strict"`, the absence of `var` throws an error in environments that support `"use strict"` for any variables not formally bound in the function signature. It basically safeguards against bad practices and potential mistakes/bugs in your code that are easy to make

**Edit:**

I actually think its worth mentioning `let` too, which is a way of explicitly binding a variable for use in a given scope. So you needn't use `var`, if you use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Check support for this keyword in your environment first!

Comment: This is incorrect because `a` was specified as a function argument.

Comment: `function f(a) { "use strict"; a = 2; }; f(); a` -> ReferenceError

Comment: your example is not syntactically valid in that comment. To be clear, if you use 'a' in a scope where 'a' has not been defined, it leaks to the global namespace. 'a' needs to be defined with var at same point, or bound formally in the scope of a function. And if you are in an environment supporting "use strict" it just blows up

Comment: The first (and last) paragraph appears to be misleading and/or wrong in the given context of a parameter. I've created a test-case showing that *without `var`*, and *with* "use strict", it doesn't "pollute the global namespace".

Comment: "use strict" applies to the scope it which it is applied. Apply it to the context outside the function scope and you shall see

Comment: `{"use strict"; function f(a) { "use strict"; a = 2; }; f(); a;}` -> ReferenceError. I still don't get it. I can remove "use strict" and add a `var` and it doesn't change how that runs.

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" when running that fiddle (Chrome 34), which agrees with my previous snippets.

Comment: Yeah thats the point of "use strict". To prevent you polluting the global namespace by using variables in scope where they are not explicitly bound (either as formal arguments or with var/let)

Comment: Anyway, make sure to address the question context in answers, that had me a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to a function. These are considered local variables inside the functions scope regardless of wether the function is called with those arguments or not.

If the function is called without supplying a value for all the arguments, the arguments that are not passed when calling the function are set to a value of `undefined`, but they are still declared inside the functions scope as locals.

```
function test(a){
    var a = 'test';
}
```

> Is the "var" required to keep the variable from going global?

No the `var` keyword is not required, and in fact should not be used, as you're redeclaring the `a` variable, and redeclaring variables is not allowed.

```
function test(a){
    a = 'test';
}
```

> Would this suffice?

Yes, that's fine and is the way it should be done. You alread have a variable named `a`, and now you're setting it to a different value.

> How about if the function is called with a undefined?

```
function test(a){
    a = 'test';
}
test();
```

As mentioned above, it doesn't matter, the argument `a` is still declared as a local variable inside the function, the value is just set to `undefined`, so the `var` keyword should not be used as you're not creating a new variable, `a` already exists, you're just giving it a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some points to comment:

First of all, within a function variables must have `var` if they are not a reference to an outside var:

```
var outside_var = "OUT!";
var myFunction = function() {
    var inner_var = "IN";
    console.log(outside_var); //Will prompt "OUT!"
    console.log(inner_var);   //Will prompt "IN"
}
console.log(outside_var); //Will prompt "OUT!"
console.log(inner_var);   //Will prompt undefined
```

Another point is that every var defined as an argument, is already defined in function scope, you don't need to declare it with var:

```
var outside_var = "OUT!";
var myFunction = function(a) {   //imagine you call myFunction("I'M");
    var inner_var = a + " IN";
    console.log(outside_var); //Will prompt "OUT!"
    console.log(a);           //Will prompt "I'M"
    console.log(inner_var);   //Will prompt "I'M IN"
}
console.log(outside_var); //Will prompt "OUT!"
console.log(a);           //Will prompt undefined
console.log(inner_var);   //Will prompt undefined
```